# Error in RShiny: cannot open the connection

Tags: r, shiny

Running the following code

```
library(shiny)
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
load("analytics.Rdata") # load the dataframe
```

produces the following error in RShiny

> *Stack trace (innermost first):
>
>       39: readChar
>
>       38: load
>
>       37: server [G:\RProjects\Shiny2/server.R#14]
>
>        1: runApp
>  Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection*

Comment: Can you add the output of your `sessionInfo()`? And does the `load` command work from the R-Studio console?

Comment: Often this means that R cannot find the file - check to make sure that it is the same directory as your `ui` and `server` files (or include the path in your `load()`) and that the file name in your code is correct.

Comment: I have solved this error.

As @JohnPaul said, It cannot find the file. I have passed the wrong file name.

Comment: @MikeWise: load command is working from the RStudio console. Sorry I dont know how to get the output from the SessionInfo. Anyway Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: For future reference just type "sessionInfo()" at the command line  and copy the output into StackOverflow and that block format as code. Or copy a screen shot.